# d3 adding multiple chloropleth maps on one page

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 and using one of Bostock chloropleth maps(https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606). I'm trying to add multiple maps to an HTML page. Instead of being different maps, my code is repeating the same map over again. Any ideas on how to correct this?

```
<style>
counties {
  fill: none;
}

.states {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

.q0-25 { fill:#40004b; }
.q1-25 { fill:#40004b; }
.q2-25 { fill:#9970ab; }
.q3-25 { fill:#9970ab; }
.q4-25 { fill:#c2a5cf; }
.q5-25 { fill:#fee08b; }
.q6-25 { fill:#a6dba0; }
.q7-25 { fill:#a6dba0; }
.q8-25 { fill:#a6dba0; }
.q9-25 { fill:#1b7837; }
.q10-25 { fill:#1b7837; }

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Lora,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    color:#4D0788; 

}
</style>
<body>
<div id="area1"></div>
<div id="area2"></div>

<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 925,
    height = 300;

var rateById = d3.map();

var quantize = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([-10,0, 10])
    .range(d3.range(11).map(function(i) { return "q" + i + "-25"; }));

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(700)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg1 = d3.select("#area1").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "us.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "county2.tsv", function(d) { rateById.set(d.id, +d.rate); })
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;

  svg1.append("g")
      .attr("class", "counties")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return quantize(rateById.get(d.id)); })
      .attr("d", path);

  svg1.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "states")
      .attr("d", path);
}

var svg2 = d3.select("#area2").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "us.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "county1.tsv", function(d) { rateById.set(d.id, +d.rate); })
    .await(ready2);

function ready2(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;

  svg2.append("g")
      .attr("class", "counties")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return quantize(rateById.get(d.id)); })
      .attr("d", path);

  svg2.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "states")
      .attr("d", path);
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you remember to use the CSS to fill your paths according to the class (q0-9 to q8-9)?

Comment: thanks @GerardoFurtado! yes, i have the class and it's filling the maps with different colors. it's just that it's only using the data from one of the csv files. i've added my css code.

Comment: Just for curiosity, which one it's being duplicated, the first or the second tsv? If you change the order (just swap "county1.tsv" for "county2.tsv"), what data is used?

Comment: it's the second one that's being shown twice (county1.tsv)

Comment: Mmmm...listen, I never used queue, I'd simply load the json and then load the two TSVs inside the json function, but try this: change `await(ready)` for `awaitAll(ready)` (this is a wild guess...).

Comment: that didn't work. it made the first map disappear completely. do you recommend i try to load it inside the ready functions? i'm not wedded to this format.

Comment: Another wild guess: I'm just reading the documentation and Bostock uses `d3.queue()` instead of `queue()` (as in his blocks). It doesn't hurt to try changing it, but I believe it will not fix your problem. Normally, when the second one is the duplicated one, it means that something is being overwritten. Let's see if someone that uses queue shows up.

Comment: Oh, yes, I'd do this: load the json normally (`d3.json("us.json", function(data){})`) and, inside it, load the TSVs for each svg, svg1 and svg2.